# Implement MVVM architecture in Flutter Native Android code

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, mvvm, flutter-plugin

I am trying to create MVVM architecture in flutter native platform code. so that i can use viewmodel and livedata in either FLutter android plugins or android platform side.

Can anyone give a correct solution for this implementation?

Comment: It's almost similar to the BloC pattern, you should read about it.

Comment: I need to implement MVVM in android code not in dart code..so that i can send live data from android to flutter side

Answer (score 0):

Stacked package in flutter is nearby the MVVM architecture,
But in MVVM, ViewModel can be shared with more than one View but in Stacked state management, we View and ViewModel intact to each other

Here is the Stacked package.
https://pub.dev/packages/stacked

Comment: This does not answer the question. The author is asking for NATIVE plugin MVVM architecture. Not a flutter plugin with MVVM architecture.